# Window resize crashes script when paired with Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

In an attempt to use a loading gif while a longer process is running, I've moved the longer process (in the same class) to a Thread.

I haven't used threading before, but it seems to work properly for my case. The problem arises when I try to resize the window in the same function that is being called by the Thread created earlier. From my testing, this doesn't seem to cause an issue every time, but when it does occur, what's causing this issue?

The only solution I've found is moving the window resize to a function called upon another button click, but this is less than ideal.

```
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from threading import Thread
import sys

class View(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.gif()
        self.thread()

    def gif(self):
        print('gif')
    
    def thread(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.long_process)
        t1.start()
    
    def long_process(self):
        referenced_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
        l = []
        for count in referenced_list:
            df = self.func()
            l.append(df)
        #### end gif
        df = pd.concat(l, axis=1).reset_index()
    
        print(df)
        window.resize(54+(273*df.shape[1]),600) 
    
    def func(self):
        data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = View()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Adding the window.resize back in seems to cause the

Comment: You cannot access UI elements from external threads. Move the "long process" to a QThread with a custom signal that emits the data shape, and connect that signal to a function that resizes the window.

Comment: Do you know what causes the lack of access when creating a new thread? I think I understand it, but it's difficult to wrap my head around. I moved the process to a Worker QThread (specifically moveToThread), as you recommended, and I am now resizing the window back in my main thread. I appreciate the help!

Comment: There is no "lack of access", but widgets are not thread-safe, meaning that trying to access them from other threads is *not* safe. I cannot give you the specific details (I don't have deep knowledge of low-level aspects of threading and it's beyond the scope of a comment anyway), but this is a general rule that is also shared amongst almost any UI framework. It's also the reason for which widgets cannot be created in any thread but the main one, which is the one running the application.